# are strings available in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi i want to know if my String which i put in the `onCreate` method are available in my `asynctask<void,void,void>`

i declare my strings this way: `final String email1 = user.get("email");`

I call to the `AsyncTask` with an `onClick(View V) { new sendDB.execute();`

hope it it clear for you guys!

i have tried to setText to that string but i cannot to so.

What i want to know is, does it work?
and if so how can i test it?

Comment: is the async task in the same class as email1? then yes

Comment: set your text on onPostExecute methond

Comment: Use the constructor to pass the String.

Comment: @ZerO the AsyncTask extends sendDB, they are in the same activity and both in the onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `asynctask<String,void,void>` instead of `asynctask<void,void,void>`
and Simply Pass string parameter as

```
String email1 = user.get("email");
new sendDB().execute(email1);
```

In doInbackground

```
 @Override
 protected void doInBackground(String... params) {   

         String s = params[0]; // here's youre string
         ...      //rest of the code. 
 }
```

You can find more info at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your link helped me out
you are able to acces a final String in AsyncTask<void,void,void> to test it i just did a setText in onPostExecute.

Comment: @Giru Bhai: Do update your `doInBackground()` return type as per your `AsyncTask` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the String as a global and the AsyncTask should be in the same class. After that you can use  setText() in the overrided method of AsyncTask called onPostExecute()